# Can a Java Static method be visualised as, a function in python + a instance method with the same name( as of function)?

Tags: java, python, java-8

I am trying to understand Static methods in java. I have done a basic python before, so I am trying to visualise the Java's static method in Python.

Is the static method in the code below

```
class test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printHello();
    }

    public static void printHello(){
        System.out.println("This is a Java's static method");
    } 
}
```

equivalent to this?

```
def printhello():
    print("It is a printhello function")

class hello():
    def printhello(self):
        print("It is a printhello method of a instance")
```

As *static* methods can be accessed without creation of objects, `def printhello` would work like this.

And when a object is accessing static method in Java, the `instance method` provided in the python class would work like that.

If not, what would be right visualisation of a java's static method in python.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here

```
class Hello:
    def printhello(self):
        ...
```

you're passing a `self` reference to the method. This means it is an *instance* method.
A *static* method never owns a reference to an instance of its containing class by default.

Python class *static* methods are defined, usually, using the `@staticmethod` annotation, and they don't accept `self`

```
class Hello:
    @staticmethod
    def printhello():
        ...
```

So the above would become, in Java

```
class Hello {
    public static void printhello() {
        ...
    } 
}
```

---

Java doesn't have the concept of first-level functions, so this

```
def printhello():
    print("It is a printhello function")
```

isn't really translatable, but it's usually a more idiomatic way of defining free/static functions in Python.

---

As you may have understood, answering your question

> Is the static method in the code below
>   ...
>   equivalent to this?

No, it's not equivalent at all.

Comment: So the problem is, if I take of the `self `parameter and make it a class method `def printHello()` then I wouldn't be able to call it on an object of the class. which is different from static methods as they can be called standalone and on objects.

Comment: ALSO, Now I understand that static method and my interpretation are two different things and are not equivalent, BUT I WANTED TO ASK, DO THEY WORK THE SAME? as my python function can be called standalone just as static method and also on an object just as static method as well. I believe they are two different things, but is the working same?

Comment: @lynxx in Java, a `static` method can be called using the `myInstance.method()` notation or `MyClass.method()`. Free-standing functions in Python and static methods in Java are basically used in the same ways. For example, Kotlin, which is an "enhancement" from Java, allows first-level/free-standing functions.